# Math operation in SQL without select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm building up intelligence on tables and generating values and I'd like to process those values. This is not production code, but debug script, so I'd simply like to do the following in MS SQL server:

```
@declare @Value1 int;
set @Value1 = 1;
@declare @Value2 int;
set @Value2 = 2;
@declare @Value3 int;

@Value3 = @Value1 + @Value2
```

How can I perform this - no select is required at all. I've not seen anything on how to do this,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
declare @Value1 int;
set @Value1 = 1;
declare @Value2 int;
set @Value2 = 2;
declare @Value3 int;

set @Value3 = @Value1 + @Value2
```

Or even: (For Sql Server 2008+)

```
declare @Value1 int=  1;
declare @Value2 int = 2;
declare @Value3 int = @Value1 + @Value2
```

Answer (score 1):

After you do the calculation, you can do:

```
Set @Value3 = @Value1 + @Value2
Print Convert(varchar, @Value3)
```

to see the result

Answer (score 1):

## [SET Keyword](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/65e3785c-5696-476d-ab43-5fd107476cb6/sql-server-set-keyword-to-hold-multiple-values)

You have to Use Set **Keyword** here

Like this

```
SET @Value3 = @Value1 + @Value2

@declare @Value1 int;
set @Value1 = 1;
@declare @Value2 int;
set @Value2 = 2;
@declare @Value3 int;

SET @Value3 = @Value1 + @Value2
```